# How to store form data in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, indexeddb

I am implementing one form submit process, But I am not using any DB(Backend). I want to store form data in client side or browser. So I am planning to use localstorage.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">      
        <div class=" row ">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form  method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usr">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit " class="btn btn-success" formaction="../BootStrapTemplate/detail.html">Submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to store data after click on the submit button. And also it will navigate to another page(detail.html page), In detail.html I will display all information.

Some additional information I have to show in detail page, Id and Time.

[image]

I want to store data according to ID(means first time saved data id value should be 1, second time saved data value should be 2)

I will use localstorage first time. So I don't know so much about localstorage. Id should be unique per record.
According to me it a better idea. If anybody has good idea storing the data in client side, Please let me know.

I have seen one link, But I am not able to do for multiple input fields, And I also want to form of key, value JSON.

Comment: Do you want all past submission stored within local storage or just the last submission?

Comment: @Jordans Thanks for the comment. I want to all past submission stored with in local storage. For example If I will submit four record, Then four record should be in local stoarge with Unique Id

Answer (score 5):

There are some plugins available but if you don't want to use that.[Plugin-to-Save-Form-Fields-Values-To-localStorage](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-to-Save-Form-Fields-Values-To-localStorage-phoenix.html)

you can use this.

**window.localStorage** - stores data with no expiration date

***window.sessionStorage*** - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)*

**Note**:- *Before using web storage, check browser support for localStorage and sessionStorage*.

To store

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

To retrieve

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to override previuos  stored data.

Comment: You can differentiate by key - key should be unique.

Comment: Is saving personal data in localStorage safe?

Answer (score 3):

This is a multi-step process using JavaScript.  Modify your page to do the following (in order, all in JavaScript)

- form submit event - prevent default (will stop the page from posting
  data to the server)
- build object of form data
- convert form data JS object to JSON using JSON.stringify()
- set JSON string to localStorage key, such as `localStorage.myKey = myJSON;`
- redirect the page to detail.html
- access localStorage and decode JSON